# How to upload files to apache www directory using Filezilla FTP in amazon EC2 instances. Since it needs root permission, remotly I don't have that

Tags: amazon-ec2

I tried using file-zilla for various root directory. It works fine for those directory which have user permissions currently remotely connected.

Comment: You can't do this without root permissions

Answer (score 0):

What I do to work around this is to upload a (compressed) tarball into `/tmp` via the default non-root user (e.g. `ec2-user` for Amazon Linux, `ubuntu` for Ubuntu, etc).  Then I login to an interactive user and use `sudo` to extract that tarball (with uncompression) to where I need its contents.